# How to add a method to URI module

Tags: ruby

I want to download a binary file from `http` or `https` URL like:

```
URI('https://www.google.com/favicon.ico').download('google.ico')
```

I wrote the method for it like this:

```
module URI
  def download(file)
    File.open(file, 'wb') {|f| f.write(open(self).read)}
  end
end
```

This method ends up with an error `ArgumentError: extra arguments`, while following code is working.

```
file = 'google.ico'
url = 'https://www.google.com/favicon.ico')
File.open(file, 'wb') {|f| f.write(open(url).read)}
```

What am I doing wrong? How should I fix it?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn did you test that? how will `File.open` know how to download a file from a URL ?

Comment: 2nd way works because `open(uri)` uses `open-uri` library which is able to download a file.  See my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 1):

URI module doesn't download file. File class doesn't either. `open` comes from `open-uri` stdlib which is why it works in your 2nd example. If you have `curl` in your system this should work:

```
module URI
  def self.download(file_url)
    filename = file_url.split('/').last
    `curl -O #{file_url}`
  end
end
```

If you DON'T have `curl` use `open-uri`

```
require 'open-uri'
module URI
  def self.download(file_url)
    filename = file_url.split('/').last
    File.open(filename, "wb") do |saved_file|
      open(file_url, "rb") do |read_file|
        saved_file.write(read_file.read)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And call it like this

```
URI.download('https://www.google.com/favicon.ico')
```

Note, URI behaves like more like a class so you need to define the method on the base object `self` otherwise you'll need to create an instance, but since it's just a module, use `def self.some_method(some_arg)` to be able to call `URL.some_method(some_arg)`

While this works, it is not recommended for production. Why do you wanna monkey patch URI when you can simply write your own module which does this?

You're better off doing something like this:

```
module SimpleFileDownload
  require 'open-uri'
  def self.download(file_url)
    filename = file_url.split('/').last
    File.open(filename, "wb") do |saved_file|
      open(file_url, "rb") do |read_file|
        saved_file.write(read_file.read)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and call it like:

```
SimpleFileDownload.download('https://www.google.com/favicon.ico')
```

Comment: If you're not going to have instances of `SimpleFileDownload` then this should be a `module`.

Comment: Another thing to note is this might get confused by a URL such as `http://example.com/test/file.txt?id=1/2` where the query string is not properly ignored.

Comment: @tadman valid point but probably out of scope for this question. The user's example clearly provides a URL to a file location.

Comment: It'll probably work, but just adding a caveat there in case someone tries this on more convoluted URLs. Filename detection is fussy.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but actually this is not what I wanted to know about. I wanted to know cause of the error. I found out the reason, I'll write it.

Comment: @ironsand the first line of my answer does explain why your code didn't work. But glad you found solution on your own.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'm calling `Kernel.open` from `open-uri`, but inside the module `URI` `OpenURI::OpenRead` is called.

At first I added `binding.pry`

```
module URI
  def download(file)
    binding.pry
    File.open(file, 'wb') {|f| f.write(open(self).read)}
  end
end
```

And checked which method is called like this:

```
pry(#<URI::HTTPS>)> show-method open

From: /Users/ironsand/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/open-uri.rb @ line 720:
Owner: OpenURI::OpenRead
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 3

def open(*rest, &block)
  OpenURI.open_uri(self, *rest, &block)
end

pry(#<URI::HTTPS>)> exit
pry(main)> show-method open

From: /Users/ironsand/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/open-uri.rb @ line 29:
Owner: Kernel
Visibility: private
Number of lines: 11

def open(name, *rest, &block) # :doc:
  if name.respond_to?(:open)
    name.open(*rest, &block)
  elsif name.respond_to?(:to_str) &&
        %r{\A[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9+\-\.]*://} =~ name &&
        (uri = URI.parse(name)).respond_to?(:open)
    uri.open(*rest, &block)
  else
    open_uri_original_open(name, *rest, &block)
  end
end
```

To use proper method I should have called the method explicitly.

```
module URI
  def download(file)
    File.open(file, 'wb') {|f| f.write(OpenURI.open_uri(self).read)}
  end
end
```

The code above works as I expected.

Comment: You realize that in your explanation you actually showed that you do not need to be explicit but rather you just need to understand the method call and the signature. e.g. `OpenURI.open_uri(self).read` is equivalent to `open.read` or `open(&:read)` in this context because `open` is `OpenURI.open_uri(self)`